# django import with django-import-export

Tags: django, django-import-export

could anybody tell me what I did wrongly here as I am unable to see all the fields while importing data from db

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'id')
        import_id_fields = ('id',)


class UserAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = UserResource
```

As show below ss I can see only username field shows up
[image]

my csv file is shown below

```
username, email, first_name, Last_name, id
abc, abc@gmail.com, abd, de
```

and models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    trial_period = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    on_trial = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_approved = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES, default='t-2')
    paid_until = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_premium_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: csv field names are case sensitive.  pls can you post your User model

Comment: thanks for the response, I have added my user models which is extended from base user model, sorry for delayed reply. Django version is 2.2 and import-export version is 2.3.0

Comment: can't really see anything wrong... (except for 'Last_name'). Try to set a breakpoint on [this line](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L498) and see if it skips fields or throws errors

Comment: cant see any log messages with break point, is there any version conflicts, I am using django 2.2 and import-export 2.3.0

Comment: version should be fine - I'm in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222482/django-import-export) - I'll help if I can

Comment: And my python version is 3.8, as per the docs there is support up to 3.7, correct?

Comment: Does adding a comma after your `last_name` value help anything? Technically speaking the dimensions of your CSV file don't add up because you've got 5 columns and only 4 columns of data (I know you want ID empty to signify new data)

Comment: No, I have tried that way, with id and without, but no effect

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue could be caused by:

1. Having the header names in the csv not matching the model attribute names (e.g. 'Last_name' should be 'last_name').
2. Some undiscovered bug in the library or application code.

Also I notice that your csv row contains 4 fields, but you declare 5 headers (no value is provided for 'id').

Other than that I cannot see any issues.  Python 3.8 should be fine.

Please update if you found the source of the problem.

Comment: I have corrected the upper case issue and no of fields, but still the same output, couldn' find solution yet

Comment: [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222482/django-import-export)